# Sampling from matrix valued distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, random-matrices

How does random sampling from matrix valued distribution work in general?

In the univariate case we can draw from the uniform distribution over the interval from 0 to 1, then plug that value into the cdf of the distribution we want to sample from. Is there a similar procedure for matrix valued distributions?

Comment: It depends on how the matrix looks like. Do you have a specific distribution in mind?

Comment: What do you mean with matrix valued distributions? Multivariate distributions?

Comment: @callculus Examples are the wishart distribution or the matrix F-distribution.